# Issues on sending email from php mailer

Tags: php, email

I have been created, simple php code for sending email.

Here is the code:

index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

May i know, what i am missing, how can i fix this error.

Thanks.,

Comment: you miss to include "class.smtp.php"

Comment: Please check your require("class.PHPMailer.php"); & require("lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); properly path....

Comment: here is the link for full source code for php mailer http://codeviewer.org/view/code:5189

Answer (score 0):

Please check for file class.smtp.php in lib/PHPMailer/ either it is not exists or check the path in phpmailer.class.php and in your code i think SMTP details are not validate please double check for it or either remove smtp authentication `$mail->SMTPAuth = false;`  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer